# how to see the logs of added module in android project in android studio

Tags: android, android-library, vitamio

This is first time i have added any module in my project. I have added android vitamio inside my project. All the things are working except the play/pause touch listener. The code seems to be written right . i have also tried putting the listener inline but no luck. However when i debug the code and execute line by line i can see the code running as expected. I have also put log.d() command inside MediaController class to track the execution but none of the log command written in the class if vitamio module gets printed. i am wondering if the log commands of added modules do not get printed at the same window where my main project's log commands do. can one please suggest on this.

Comment: just select `No filter `in your `logcat`

Comment: no i dont see those logs there too... shouldn't they appear with my project filter ?

Answer (score 0):

Those module logs are part of the full project. You can filter and display specific log only if the module send it